# How to get Multiple Inputs?

Tags: php, html

I want to get Multiple Inputs and use them later when Press Submit Button

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Class Details</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <?php
         $noOfSections=0;
         $sectionNameArray= array();
         $sectioerr="";
         if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
             if(!empty($_POST["noOfSections"]))
                 $noOfSections = $_POST["noOfSections"];
             else
                 $sectioerr="Must Enter Number of Sections";
         }
         ?>
      <form action="classdetails.php" method="POST">
         <p>Enter Number of Sections : </p>
         <input type="text" name="noOfSections">*<?php echo $sectioerr?>
         <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter"><br>
      </form>
      <form action="classdetails.php" method="POST">
         //Thats the real area about which I am Asking Questions
         <?php
            if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){//it is USED to prosses THE STATEMETS BELOW only when the above Submit Button is pressed 
            echo "<p>Enter Names of Sections : </p><br>";
                for($x=0;$x<$noOfSections;$x++){
                    echo "Enter Name of Section No. ".($x+1)."<br>";
                    echo "<input type=\"text\">*";
                }
                    echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submitnames\"><br>";
            }
            ?>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

I want to Get Multiple Inputs when I press Submit Button Having name attribute "submitnames"

Comment: and you're actual question is?

Comment: If you want to post more inputs, just add them to the form? The inputs needs the `name` attribute set or they won't be submitted though. If you do: `type="text" name="generated[]"` (note the `[]` at the end of the name). Now, when the form is submitted, the `$_POST['generated']` will contain an array with all the input values.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [] to the end of your dynamic input names

```
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"names[]"\>*";
```

Edit :Thanks to  Magnus Eriksson for pointing out my mistake in the comments.

Comment: Looking at the code, it's most likely `<input type=\"text\">` (which is generated in a loop) that needs names, not the submit-button itself.

Comment: Thanks! It Worked